# one app shows Unable to execute dex: GC overhead limit exceeded GC overhead limit exceeded in eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse, garbage-collection

I have tried to read some of the questions answered on stackoveflow and changed eclipse.ini according to this:

[image]

Now every app is running properly except one. It shows this message:

Unable to execute dex: GC overhead limit exceeded
GC overhead limit exceeded

It forces eclipse to crash. Is there any other way to fix this or is this my projects problem ?

Thanks!

Comment: `--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
 512m
-XX:MaxPermSize=1024m`    remove `--launcher.XXMaxPermSize` one time its there for twice. and add `-XX:MaxPermSize=1024m`

Comment: I did this but nothing happened , it now showing

Conversion to Dalvik format failed: Unable to execute dex: GC overhead limit exceeded

Comment: have you tried increasing the limit further? maybe the compiler just needs that much ram.

Answer (score 0):

locate the

> eclipse.ini

file in your Eclipse's installation directory. Then Copy and past the following content :

```
openFile
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
1024m
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
1024m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.appendVmargs
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.5
-Xms512m 
-Xmx1024m
```